# Where is Android SDK option to install on Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager, android-sdk-2.1

I've just formatted and installed a fresh windows 10. Next, I downloaded Android Studio and didn't see the Android SDK option to install.

[Android_Studio_Install_Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDTgW.png)

I installed it nevertheless. Naturally, after I opened Android Studio, it opened a window saying that it needs Android SDK to work properly. I went to Android Studio homepage again, and downloaded 
[SDK Command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FaCZ.png)
Extracted it to c:\program files\android . I opened Android Studio again and tried to pinpoint the tools folder inside c:\program files\android\tools as the location of SDK and received this warning:
[not valid home for SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ8iW.png)

I typed CMD with administrator rights, entered the tools folder, and executed android update sdk and it downloaded some files and wrote after a while repositores.cfg could not be loaded.

I am out of options now. I need the SDK to compile ! I can't find an offline install on internet. How can Android Studio be installed without the SDK ? I do not understand... and before you ask, there's no android folder on c:\users\my_user\AppData\local ...is there a bug on the latest Android Studio install program? I can't have SDK already installed because this is a fresh install of windows 10. Help on this matter will be much aprecciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can open Android Studio then go to Tools --> Android --> SDK manager and you should be able to install or uninstall SDKs from there

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. I had settings imported from my previous Android Studio installation and my Android SDK Location was set to a folder which was empty. I couldn't figure out how to download new Android SDK but after clicking "Edit" next to "Android SDK Location" (in Default Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Setttins > Android SDK) Android Studio opened a dialog box where I could choose to install/update my SDK or just selected components of it.