# Why is there no Android in Android Studio 3.3?

Tags: android-studio, installation

I installed AS 3.3 in Windows 10. It has no Android options e.g. no android option in create project or run. There are Kotlin, Gradle and other options.

I downloaded the AS/SDK bundle 2.3. This worked OK but then I tried to update it to 3.3. Running the 3.3 installer uninstalled the old 2.3 but kept its settings. But again now no Android.

What am I doing wrong?

PS I have SDK installed at ...\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

EDIT: the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624896/android-studio-doesnt-show-options-for-create-android-projects) says `Click Configure and from top, navigate to 'Appearances & Behaviour' > 'System Settings' > 'Android SDK'` but I have no `Android SDK` option.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587806/where-is-android-sdk-option-to-install-on-android-studio) says go to `Tools --> Android --> SDK manager` but I do not have an `Android` option under Tools.

Comment: Have you check if your Android plugin is enabled?

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an error saying 'android support disabled'. It gave a link to enable it, restarted and now it is OK.